# Remove first 3 characters in string using a condition statement

Tags: python, string, pandas

Can anyone Kindly help please?
I'm trying to remove three of the first characters within the string using the statement:

`Data['COUNTRY_CODE'] = Data['COUNTRY1'].str[3:]`

This will create a new column after removing the first three values of the string. However, I do not want this to be applied to all of the values within the same column so was hoping there would be a way to use a conditional statement such as 'Where' in order to only change the desired strings?

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Comment: what  are the condtions?

Comment: Are you want to put the first three values in the new columns?

Comment: Yes I am using Pandas in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using pandas so your condition check can be like:

```
condition_mask = Data['COL_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK'] == 'SOME CONDITION'
```

Your new column can be created as:

```
# Assuming you want the first 3 chars as COUNTRY_CODE
Data.loc[condition_mask, 'COUNTRY_CODE'] = Data['COUNTRY1'].str[:3]
```